# one to many relationship - one item with many comments

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, one-to-many

I'm trying to pull data that exists in a couple of different tables. Specifically, I have a table for bugs, and a table for "posts" (comments/updates) on those bugs. For each bug, there may be no comments, one comment, or many. I want ALL bugs returned, and all comments returned (although I'd like to leave out updates), but as columns, rather than one row per bug/comment.

Here's where I started:

```
select 
b.bg_id,
b.bg_reported_date as "Date Created",
b.bg_short_desc as "Summary",
bp.bp_comment_search as "Comment Body", 
s.st_name as "Status",
p.pr_name as "Priority",
bp.bp_type as "Update Type"
from 
bugs b
inner join bug_posts bp on b.bg_id = bp.bp_bug
inner join statuses s on b.bg_status = s.st_id
inner join priorities p on b.bg_priority = p.pr_id
--where bp.bp_type = 'comment'
order by b.bg_id asc
```

This gave me one row for each comment, which is not what I want. as you can see, i also tried to limit the results to only include posts of type "comment" but this excluded any bugs that didn't have comments, so i took that out.

I found this article which seemed related: [JOIN in SQL with one-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472456/join-in-sql-with-one-to-many-relationship)

But i can't get it to work with my query. here's what I have so far:

```
select 
b.bg_id,
b.bg_reported_date as "Date Created",
b.bg_short_desc as "Summary",
--bp.bp_comment_search as "Comment Body", 
s.st_name as "Status",
p.pr_name as "Priority",
--bp.bp_type as "Update Type"
from
bugs b
left outer join
    (select bp_comment_search as "Comment Body"
    from bug_posts
    group by bp_bug) bp on bp.bp_bug = b.bg_id
--inner join bug_posts bp on b.bg_id = bp.bp_bug

inner join statuses s on b.bg_status = s.st_id
inner join priorities p on b.bg_priority = p.pr_id
--where bp.bp_type = 'comment'
order by b.bg_id asc
```

My SQL knowledge is VERY limited, but any help anyone could provide would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what kind of SQL are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, MSSql) and what version of that?

Comment: I added an example to my answer below. The part where you put the comments to columns (instead of rows) -> Why do you want that? Could you give an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You should leave that filter to 'only comments' in there but change the 'INNER JOIN' to a 'LEFT JOIN' then you will see all bugs weather or not they have comments.

The other function you are looking for is called 'pivot' it traverses rows (of comments) into columns.

I do not know SQL Server 2008 myself but found this link for the pivot:
[directly to microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

So, except for the 'comments to columns' action this could be your query:

```
select 
b.bg_id,
b.bg_reported_date as "Date Created",
b.bg_short_desc as "Summary",
bp.bp_comment_search as "Comment Body", 
s.st_name as "Status",
p.pr_name as "Priority",
from
bugs b
left join bug_posts bp on b.bg_id = bp.bp_bug AND bp.bp_type = 'comment'
inner join statuses s on b.bg_status = s.st_id
inner join priorities p on b.bg_priority = p.pr_id
order by b.bg_id asc
```

Comment: i want the comments as columns rather than rows because I intend to export this to excel (CSV) and then import it into another tool (JIRA). this tool expects each comment as a column, and each bug as only one row. Does that make sense? if not, i'll add examples of what I'd like to see.

Comment: I suspect that PIVOT is at best crass overkill for this problem, and at worst won't solve it at all.  What are you proposing that we use as the pivot key that will not lead to each comment getting its own set of columns?  Presumably you need to assign each comment a sequence number relative to a group defined by the bug key.  That can be probably be done, but then the bigger issue remains: why do it when you can just process the comment rows?

Comment: @user1108721 as sacundim pointed out that is something like a "BAD IDEA". You either have to sacrifice comments (if there are too many) or have empty columns all the time (if there are too few). I would suggest you use the example of mine and pack the comments to the CSV manually in your programming language.

Answer (score 0):

> For each bug, there may be no comments, one comment, or many. I want ALL bugs returned, and all comments returned (although I'd like to leave out updates), but as columns, rather than one row per bug/comment.

That cannot be done for an arbitrary number of comments.  This would require that your query return a variable number of columns, depending on the data—but in SQL, the number of columns in a result set is determined completely by the query and the table definitions.

You're going to need to pull in one row per comment (either from a query similar to yours, or from a query that just pulls comment data), and add each comment data row manually to the object that represents its bug.  (Most Object-Relational Mappers handle one-to-many relationships in this way, BTW.)